# Solving to get free falling coordinate as function of arbitrary coordinate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

From  weinberg's gravitation, EQ : $3.2.11$

$$\frac{\partial^2 \zeta^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu} = \Gamma^\lambda _{\mu \nu}\frac{\partial\zeta^\alpha}{\partial x ^\lambda}$$

The solution to this differential equation is given as

$$\zeta^\alpha(x) = a^\alpha + b^\alpha _{\mu}(x^\mu - X^\mu) + \frac{1}{2} b^\alpha _\lambda\Gamma^\lambda _{\mu \nu}(x^\mu - X^\mu)(x^\nu - X^\nu) + \cdot \cdot \cdot $$

How can it be solved?

Comment: Should that be $\partial x^\mu$ rather than $\partial x^\lambda$ on the left?

Comment: Thanks for the noticing that. I've corrected it

Comment: I'm having trouble with the language here. Paraphrasing: "The solution to this differential equation is ...", then: "How can it be solved?" Do you mean to ask: "How does one show that this solution (2nd equation) satisfies the equation above (1st equation)?"?

Comment: @MarkWayne yes i'm saying " how i can obtain the solution"

Comment: @Aftnix: I think all that's going on here is plugging into the equation the general Taylor expansion (up to second order terms) and comparing coefficients. Do you need an explanation how to do this?